# URL Removal - Incorrect URL

Tags: google, google-search-console

I have recently updated a website for a friend and found that the WordPress 'Hello World' page was showing in Google results. I used the URL removal tool and asked for this to be removed, however it removed the homepage so now it is not showing in Google, only the Hello World one is.

I went back in and 'Cancelled' the request but it is still not showing, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: You're not blocking search engines in Wordpress are you? Your homepage shouldn't have been removed from Google's index unless you left the field blank in the URL removal tool in Google WMT.

Comment: my robots.txt has the following:User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/

and my sitemap has 4 pages listed which Webmaster Tools says 4 have been submitted but nothing for indexed. I submitted the 8th and it says processed 10th.

Comment: What's the URL of your website?

Comment: Link to the website from Google+. That should get it indexed again quickly - there doesn't appear to be an issue at present, probably Googlebot isn't visiting your website frequently so it's a case of giving it some more time.

Comment: OK, Thanks for help Geoff. I wondered if I was just being impatient. I'll give it a bit more time. With regards to the Google+ account, can it be any or would it need to be associated with the site? Just out of interest, why might this get it indexed quickly?

Comment: Anywhere on Google+ will do. Recent tests have shown that Google favour content on their own network and will visit and crawl links from their own network pretty fast.

Comment: perhaps you wanna try permanent redirect from hello world page to main page for the moment. until google indexed your main page then remove this permanent redirect thing.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be meta tags on your site which tell Google not to index it. Line  25 in your source code states:

```
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="none" />
```

If you remove those tags and resubmit the pages for indexing in Webmaster Tools then you should get back in the index soon enough.

Comment: Sorry, do you know how I remove these lines? I'm using Yoast SEO Plugin in Wordpress, I can only presume I have set something in there that is causing the issue.

Comment: I dont know exactly, try disabling the plugin and seeing if that removes the tags, and if it does then at least you know exactly where to look further.

Comment: Try settings -> reading -> search engine visibility  ([Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen))